# Do the Russian Railways offer discounts in November?

Tags: trains, planning, russia, trans-siberian, siberia

I will start my trans-Siberia trip on Nov.18 in Moscow.

Do the Russian Railways offer discounts in November?

I am not a student. I just expect special discount since Nov. should be low season.

Comment: What kind of discount are you asking about? Are you asking if their normal discounts (such as for students, off-peak travel, etc) are suspended during November? Or of they offer November-specific discounts? Or if they offer some specific discount that applies to you? I think you need to make your question much more specific.

Comment: I am just hoping.

Comment: I was just wondering why you might get special discounts if you lived in the town of Nov.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that there will be some special actions in November for Russian Railways. May be some additional trains for the [Unity Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_Day_(Russia)), but this isn't the case for you.

But I have a good news for you - there always some discounts depending on the train, and some special pricing for international trains. Bad news is that the main interesting actions are in Russian.

For International trains you can explore [this page](http://eng.rzd.ru/statice/public/en?STRUCTURE_ID=45) on Enlish version of their site, but this information only about international trains, so I wouldn't get the details here.

For inner trains there are two main option to save the money (all links will be in Russian, please try to use the Google Translate for it):

- [Dynamical Pricing Strategy](http://pass.rzd.ru/static/public/ru?STRUCTURE_ID=5227&layer_id=3290&id=2335)
- [Lucky Tuesday](http://pass.rzd.ru/static/public/ru?STRUCTURE_ID=5316)

First one is strategy to encourage the passengers to but tickets earlier - for inner trains you can buy ticket **up to 45 days** from deliver date, **up to 60 days** for international trains, and for some trains you can rally save money with early purchase.
The process still in progress, as for many trains carrier has a monopoly, and can't quickly introduce such discount according to the laws. You may be interested in route Moscow - Ufa - Moscow, other destinations are far too away from Trans-Siberian railroad.
The main thing you should note about this option is that the [Couchette (platzkart, плацкарт) class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Couchette_car) tickets aren't available, so you have to buy expensive tickets, but with a discount :) Note that upper seats in [Corridor coach (kupe, купе) class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corridor_coach) are cheaper than lower ones. [Sleeping car](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeping_car) are also available for some trains.

Second one is a repeatable discount, so each Tuesday you can buy cheap platzkart tickets even with discount. Right now, today you can buy ticket for **October, 7 to 27** for a set of trains. Some of them are quite unusual, but Moscow - Ufa still available. Bad news is that the trains can be a random choice, and the seats are platzkart-sided, which isn't very comfortable, and personally I suggest you not to try this one out without good company:

[image]

So, if you're feeling lucky, choose train you like, and Good Luck with your travel!

Comment: The other tab on that page says these only apply to select routes. I dunno what route exactly the OP wants, but at least Vladivostok (Владивосток) is not mentioned there. However there's this thing: http://pass.rzd.ru/static/public/ru?STRUCTURE_ID=5267 - "seasonal tariff adjustments" - and that page says there's 0.9 coefficient (more or less like 10 percent discount) between Sep 13 and Dec 23. That's not the best you can get - there's 0.5 coefficient for May 8 and May 9. Also it's can be larger than one - up to 1.2 on some popular date ranges.